# How to generate java class object from Master XSD that has reference xsd in java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have an xml file that has reference xsd .Master reference xsd also has many reference xsd .

My question is how do I convert xsd into java classes that has many reference xsd.

Do I have to provide all referenced xsd in the same location ?

Here is my xsd structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:env="http://data.schemas.tfn.fsr.com/Envelope/2008-05-01/" xmlns="http://fsr.com/Fundamental/2011-07-07/" xmlns:sou="http://fsr.com/FinancialSource/2011-07-07/" xmlns:pe="http://fsr.com/FinancialPeriod/2011-07-07/" xmlns:fs="http://fsr.com/FinancialStatement/2011-07-07/" xmlns:ir="http://fsr.com/FinancialInstrumentRelationship/2011-07-07/" xmlns:fl="http://fsr.com/FinancialLineItem/2011-07-07/" xmlns:seg="http://fsr.com/FinancialSegment/2011-07-07/" xmlns:sli="http://fsr.com/StandardizedLineItem/2011-07-07/" xmlns:ss="http://fsr.com/StandardizedStatement/2011-07-07/" xmlns:ful="http://fsr.com/FundamentalLineItem/2011-07-07/" xmlns:esg="http://fsr.com/ESGSupportingInfo/2011-07-07/" xmlns:cor="http://fsr.com/CoraxData/2012-10-25/" xmlns:al="http://fsr.com/FundamentalAnalytics/2011-07-07/" xmlns:md="http://data.schemas.financial.fsr.com/metadata/2010-10-10/" targetNamespace="http://fsr.com/Fundamental/2011-07-07/" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0.0">
    <xs:import namespace="http://data.schemas.tfn.fsr.com/Envelope/2008-05-01/" schemaLocation="../../Envelope/2008-05-01/ContentEnvelope.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="FundamentalDataItem.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FinancialSource/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FinancialSource.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FinancialPeriod/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FinancialPeriod.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FinancialStatement/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FinancialStatement.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FinancialInstrumentRelationship/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FundamentalInstrument.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FinancialLineItem/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FinancialLineItem.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FinancialSegment/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FinancialSegment.xsd"/>
    <!--<xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/StandardizedLineItem/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="StandardizedLineItem.xsd"/>-->
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/StandardizedStatement/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="StandardizedStatement.xsd"/>
    <!--xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FundamentalLineItem/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FundamentalLineItem.xsd"/-->
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/CoraxData/2012-10-25/" schemaLocation="TRFCorax.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FundamentalAnalytics/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FundamentalSeries.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FundamentalAnalytics/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FundamentalSeriesPeriod.xsd"/>
  <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FundamentalAnalytics/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FundamentalSeriesFiscalCalendar.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FundamentalAnalytics/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FundamentalAnalytic.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://data.schemas.financial.fsr.com/metadata/2010-10-10/" schemaLocation="../../Metadata/2010-10-10/RelationshipDataItem.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://data.schemas.financial.fsr.com/metadata/2010-10-10/" schemaLocation="../../Metadata/2010-10-10/IdentifierDataItem.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://data.schemas.financial.fsr.com/metadata/2010-10-10/" schemaLocation="../../Metadata/2010-10-10/AdminStatusDataItem.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/ESGSupportingInfo/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="ESGSupportingInfo.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FinancialStatement/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FinancialStatementLineItem.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/FinancialStatement/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="FinancialStatementNonNumericLineItem.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://fsr.com/StandardizedStatement/2011-07-07/" schemaLocation="StandardizedStatementLineItem.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="FundamentalDataItem" mixed="false">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="env:DataItemBase">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="Fundamental" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="FinancialPeriodDataItem" mixed="false">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="env:DataItemBase">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="pe:FinancialPeriod" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

here is my xsd tree structure

Main Xsd

```
<xs:import schemaLocation="../../Envelope/2008-05-01/Mentale.xsd" namespace="http://data.schemas.tfn.son.com/Envelope/2008-05-01/"/>

<xs:include schemaLocation="MentaleDataItem.xsd"/>
<xs:complexType mixed="false" name="MentaleDataItem">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="env:DataItemBase">
            <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="Mentale"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB for this. see [Oracle Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)

JAXB can be used for manipulating XML.

JAXB will take an XML Schema that you write and create a set of classes that correspond to that schema. The JAXB utilities will create the hierarchy of data structures for manipulating that XML.

JAXB can then be used to read an XML file, and then create instances of the generated classes - laden with the data from your XML. JAXB also does the reverse: takes java classes, and generates the corresponding XML.

I like JAXB because it is easy to use, and comes with > Java 1.6 (if you are using 1.5 or less, you can download the JAXB .jars.) The way it creates the class hierarchy is intuitive, and in my experience, does a decent job abstracting away the "XML" so that I can focus on "data".

There are other softwares which facilitates this, eg: https://www.liquid-technologies.com/

Comment: So i have to create java class for each XSD separately is yes then how will i  link them.Can you please give an example .I am new to xml and xsd

Comment: JAXB will take care of everything... Just go through the documentation.

Comment: I have three XSD that is refereed to another and that is one is referred to another i have updated my XSD tree structure also .Please have a look once.Why i am asking is that  i have tried but throws exception